# g++ writing on memory and messing up with SSH process on BBB?

Tags: ssh, compilation, g++, zxing, beagleboneblack

This is a crazy question and maybe it does not make sense at all, but I need some help here. I am developing an application in a BeagleBone Black (BBB) in C++ (compiling with g++). Just as a matter of information, BBB is an open-source hardware board (like Arduino or Raspberry Pi) which can be accessed through SSH (and only via SSH). I use opencv and zxing libraries. Everything was working fine until I started using zxing (Google's open source QR reader library). So when I started compiling my application including this library, it worked fine until I turn the BBB off. Once I turned it back on, I am not able to connect via SSH anymore. This is something really weird and I cannot think why would this happen.

Recently, I had a problem in my application related to the memory area where some variables are and those areas being overwritten (checking with gdb). So I started wondering that maybe the BBB do not handle memory properly and something related to the SSH process is being overwritten. I do not know how SSH processes are handled on a computer, so I do not know if this is some crazy idea. Can anyone think if it is possible that the compilation (or zxing) is related somehow with the SSH not working after that? Is that even possible?

BBB uses [Angstrom distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85ngstr%C3%B6m_distribution).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is more likely with the driver you have to talk to the BBB.  Try uninstalling the drivers and see if that helps.  I got to the point where my Mac would not talk to my BBB at all, even with fresh installs of HoRNDIS and the FTDI driver.  Everything works really well if you connect via an Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the Beaglebone storage got full when you compiled zxing, so in next boots sshd can't be started.